# Expanding PHP: Hypertext Processor

Tags: php, recursion

I am learning recursion now in my programming class, and while I understand how to use recursion for things like factorials and backtracking algorithms, I've been trying to wrap my head around how a recursive acronym, such as PHP, would be iterated for quite some time know. How could one write a program to iterate the expansion of PHP n times?

EDIT: I need to clarify my question
PHP is a recursive acronym, stands for PHP: Personal home page. So if you were to expand PHP: Hypertext processor an infinite number of times, would it look like PHP:Hypertext Processor Hypertext processor hypertext processor... or soemthing different

Comment: In php? I think you have to provide the code you have so far and/or errors.. for now I can only think in something like getString(int deep)..

Comment: ...What in the world are you trying to ask?

Comment: Put an include statement inside a while loop?

Comment: Actually (now) PHP stands for "PHP, Hypertext Preprocessor", what you wrote is not exactly a recursive acronym

Comment: Are you asking to build a function/method that would effectively produce: `PHP: Personal Home Page` on any reference to `PHP` which would more or less go on forever in this case since `PHP` is mentioned in the expanded definition?

Comment: Basically you have to callback the same function until your end is reached. You have to provide an end or you will fall into an endless recursion, usually you give a limit calls or "when reaching 0 or 1 do something else". Try to code fibonacci or factorial, math functions to pratice recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am completely guessing as to what you're asking, but if I'm right it would be something like this:

```
function recursePHP($n) {
    if ($n <= 0)
        return 'PHP';

    return recursePHP($n-1) . 'Hypertext Processor';
}
```

This is taking a recursive function approach to your question that would spit out, given n=2: "PHP Hypertext Processor Hypertext Processor"

I see this as the correct way to recurse through the acronym, as thinking about the first iteration you end up with "PHP Hypertext Processor", the PHP in this resolves to "PHP Hypertext Processor" so that becomes "**PHP Hypertext Processor** Hypertext Processor" with the bold section being the PHP in the first iteration, etc. Until you've iterated through the specified number of recursions then you don't resolve PHP and end up with PHP at the beginning followed by `n` "Hypertext Processor"s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "PHP: Hypertext Processor" would expand to "PHP: Hypertext ProcessorHP: Hypertext Processor" after the first iteration.

Try this:

```
function iteration($i = 0) {
    if ($i < 10)
    {
        echo iteration($i + 1) . 'HP: Personal Home Page';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'P';
    }
}

iteration();
```

Not tested, but enough to get you started.

Edit: hmm, thinking about it, I'm *really* not sure how this acryonym is meant to recurse `:-)`.

Comment: I think it is recursive, but maybe not the recursion you want. It is recursive since it can call iteration inside iteration.

Comment: @helloworld: can you clarify? Any function that is defined in terms of a call to itself is recursive.

Comment: @halfer ah missed that sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is an acroym for PHP hypertext processor I guess the result of expanding would be PHP (hypertext processor ){Inf} since the first P in PHP expads to PHP while the other two letters add hypertext processor for each iteration.